# How to import lldb module for python on Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lldb

I need a lldb python library to debug my python script. I made my python environment configuration following the lldb.llvm.org's instructions. But I got some errors as follow:

```
/Users/heping/Desktop/Scripts/.env/python-3.7.3/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 57996 --file /Users/heping/Desktop/Scripts/RevealServerCommands.py
pydev debugger: process 59879 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 193.5662.61)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import _lldb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lldb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from . import _lldb
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__lldb)
```

And the PyCharm project structure is as picture showing blow:

[image: PyCharm Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lldb python module shipped with Xcode builds against a specific version of Python.

Prior to Xcode 11 lldb was built against the Python2.7.1 in /System/Library/Frameworks.  Starting with Xcode 11, lldb is built against the version of Python 3 (currently 3.7.3) that ships with the Xcode from which you got your lldb.  You can locate the proper python3 command line tool by running `xcrun python3`.

We haven't had much success getting the lldb module we build against this 3.7.3 Python to load into other hand-built Pythons.  I'm not sure that this is particularly well supported by Python, though I don't know of anybody who has looked into what it would take to support this.

We do use a lot of the Python C API's in the lldb bindings, so we are more bound to the Python version than pure Python modules.  Anyway, at present if you need to load the lldb module into a python you have installed from elsewhere, you will most likely need to hand-build lldb against that python library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that I could solve this problem by changing my python interpreter to ‘xcrun python3’ to be compatible with Xcode lldb version, or otherwise, bulding lldb against the specific python interpreter that I use? Right?

Comment: Yes, either of those would work, though the former - if possible - will be much simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much and I will check it out.

Comment: I've try the former, and it works really well. Thank you. But I have another question: How could I debug my script under Xcode lldb, or in another word,  how could I attach a python debugger with my script under the lldb environment. Any clue will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Python debuggers.  When I want to debug Python under lldb (for instance to debug lldb Python data formatters and the like) I just modify the Python code, and add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: I haven't explored how to get external debuggers to work.  If you had a Python debugger that could attach to arbitrary interpreters, that would work but I don't know if that's possible.  If there's an open source debugger you can build it against Xcode's Python.framework.  It might be better to ask this as a separate general Python question: "How to I attach a Python debugger to some externally provided python interpreter".  Somebody in the Python community will know whether that's possible or not.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much. I know what you mean.  And I think I just rely too much on the IDE, I could just use the built in debugger module. But what I’m asking may be if it’s possible to debug python remotely, just like Node.js. If it’s possible I could use my IDE to deal with it. I will find out it or ask another question. Thanks again. : )

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS PyCharm go `Preferences\Python Interpreter\` Then click on the Settings buttons and `Show All`.

[image]

[image]

Other answers said you need this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python3')
import lldb
```

With the above setting, it worked with just `import lldb`.

Comment: Yes, you’re telling how to change Python Interpreter and lldb Python library to the Xcode specific version.  I’ve successfully done that. But a new problem I face is how to debug.  Because the Python scripts is not execute directly, it is invoked by the Xcode lldb process, I don’t know how to attach a Python debugger to that process. I’ve tried to use the Python internal debugger module `pdb`. But when I use the internal debugger command from the Xcode lldb console, lldb get stuck, and I don’t know why. Do you know how to solve this debugging problem? Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: are you connecting from Terminal `lldb attach -p $(ps x | grep -i -m1 my_app | awk '{print $1}')`?  That will connect to an iOS simulator app from the command line called `my_app`

Comment: Oh, I haven't try this way before. I just use a Xcode debugger condition break point to execute lldb command to load my python script, or just pause the debugger process and the execute lldb command to load my python script. I would try your way to find out if the `pdb` command could work properly.

Comment: I would like to get `pdb` working properly. But if it helps, I wrote quite a few breakpoints examples on here: https://github.com/rustymagnet3000/lldb_debugger_and_reversing_ios_apps#breakpoints

Comment: @rustMagnet  I read your GitHub project  few minutes ago. It's awesome. But I have a question, that how you debug your Python script. Would you please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Neal.Marlin I found myself writing scripts line by line in the script bridge, so I know they work, before putting them into a full script.  `lldb) script`  Not perfect but it helps me find errors quickly.

Answer (score 0):

## About installing or using lldb python lib in mac.

### If you are using system python: /usr/bin/python3

If you are currently using the ORIGIN python in your system, you should probably use the lldb inside:
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python`

However the path might be different form what I just provided. So here are some steps to ascertain what lldb path you should focus.

1. In your terminal, run `which python` and `which lldb`, you should make sure the current python and lldb is under the same folder: `/usr/bin/`
2. If so, run `lldb -P` to see the lldb python library, it should already be in your mac
3. Then, config your path, add the following path into your zshrc or bash_profile depending on the shell which your are using for now:

```
# PYTHONPATH is an environment variable that is used to 
# specify the location of Python libraries. It is typic-
# ally used by developers to ensure that their code can
# find the required Python libraries.
PYTHONPATH=`lldb -P`
```

4. Remember to run `source ~/.zshrc`, then you could run `python`, then you could see the following output:

```
➜  ~ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug 11 2023, 19:44:49)
[Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lldb
>>>
```

### If you are using conda python: /Users/username/opt/miniconda3/bin/python

You could just run `conda install -c conda-forge lldb` inside your terminal. You could also refer to this webpage: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/lldb.

Then you could test your lldb.

```
(base) ➜  ~ python
Python 3.9.18 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Aug 30 2023, 03:53:08)
[Clang 15.0.7 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lldb
>>>
```

Hope it helps!